# Computing the Cosine Similarity of two sets of vectors in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, cosine-similarity

Hi fellow Stackoverflow users,

I am currently struggling with a solution to this problem:

I've got 2 2d tensors:

```
a = Tensor(shape=[600,52]) # 600 vectors of length 52
b = Tensor(shape=[16000,52]) # 1600 vectors of length 52
```

I am trying to compute the cosine similarity of all vector combinations and store them in a 3rd tensor.

```
similarity = Tensor(shape=[600, 16000])
```

My questions now are the following

a) I am not quite sure on how to implement this in a non-iterative way, I thought about using the broadcasting semantics in combination with tf.losses.cosine_distance, but I can not quite wrap my head around what that would actually look like.

b) Depending on the implementation (if tf.losses.cosine_distance is used, which requires matching dimensions for both input tensors) the memory footprint might become quite large, as it would require to create two tensors of shape [600, 1600, 52] in order to compute the distances for all combinations of vectors. Could you think of any possibility to work around that?

I hope that I was able to convey my thoughts in an understandable manner, thank you for your help

Best,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compute that simply like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Vectors
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[600, 52])
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[16000, 52])
# Cosine similarity
similarity = tf.reduce_sum(a[:, tf.newaxis] * b, axis=-1)
# Only necessary if vectors are not normalized
similarity /= tf.norm(a[:, tf.newaxis], axis=-1) * tf.norm(b, axis=-1)
# If you prefer the distance measure
distance = 1 - similarity
```